# How to perform permutation matrix multiplication in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, permutation, matrix-multiplication

Permutation matrices A and B are square and contains only a single 1 in each row. All of the rows are unique.
I've added my first attempt as an answer. I hope someone has a faster solution.

```
def permmult(a, b):
    """Multiply two permutation matrices.

     a,b: lists of positive integers and zero."""
    c = []
    for row in a:
        c.append(b[-row])
    return c
```

Comment: How much faster do you think it can be done?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output. You initial statement that A and B are permutation matrix (containing only 1s and 0s) is contradicted by your comment about variable `a,b` in the code.  The code assumes two lists (not matrices) unless you are using numpy and forgot to tell us.  Also, if a and b only contained 1s and 0s, the resulting c would be a combination of 1st and last element of b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutation matrices are a nice mathematical concept but they are not how you would approach reordering elements in a vector programmatically (unless you're trying to do something special with numpy).

Creating a permutation matrix (P) from a vector (K) of reordered indexes can be done like this:

```
def pMatBuild(A):
    return [ [int(a==b) for b in range(len(A))] for a in A ]

K = [0,3,1,4,2]
P = pMatBuild(K)
```

output:

```
for line in P: print(line)

[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Applying this permutation matrix to another vector (i.e. multiplying) cans be done like this:

```
def pMatApply(P,V):
    return [ V[row.index(1)] for row in P ] # inefficient lookup of 1 on each row
```

output:

```
V = "ABCDE"    
print(pMatApply(P,V))

['A', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'C']
```

But, in code, what would be a lot more efficient than a permutation matrix would be to use the original index vector K:

```
V = "ABCDE"
print([V[i] for i in K])
['A', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter if not faster:

```
def permmult(a,b):
    return [b[-r] for r in a]
```

Comment: A bit faster indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The best I achieved so far...

```
def permmult(a, b):
    """Multiply two permutation matrices.

     a,b: lists of positive integers and zero."""
    c = []
    for row in a:
        c.append(b[-row])
    return c
```